# Unable to start nextjs 14 development server with yarn berry latest version

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js14

I am unable to start development server with nextjs 14 with **yarn**. It is working fine with *pnpm* and *npm* but the problem is only with **yarn**

The error message:

```
E:\Programming\TM\test\.yarn\__virtual__\next-virtual-a4f48e3656\0\cache\next-npm-14.1.0-a62036d298-077fd76a6f.zip\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\conf\index.js:1
(()=>{var e={6474:(e,r,t)=>{"use strict";var a=t(9258),s=t(2603),i=t(7731),o=t(2961),n=t(6424),l=t(2015),f=t(9233),c=t(1966),u=t(8716);e.exports=Ajv;Ajv.prototype.validate=validate;Ajv.prototype.compile=compile;Ajv.prototype.addSchema=addSchema;Ajv.prototype.addMetaSchema=addMetaSchema;Ajv.prototype.validateSchema=validateSchema;Ajv.prototype.getSchema=getSchema;Ajv.prototype.removeSchema=removeSchema;Ajv.prototype.addFormat=addFormat;Ajv.prototype.errorsText=errorsText;Ajv.prototype._addSchema=_addSchema;Ajv.prototype._compile=_compile;Ajv.prototype.compileAsync=t(2694);var h=t(6765);Ajv.prototype.addKeyword=h.add;Ajv.prototype.getKeyword=h.get;Ajv.prototype.removeKeyword=h.remove;Ajv.prototype.validateKeyword=h.validate;var d=t(6343);Ajv.ValidationError=d.Validation;Ajv.MissingRefError=d.MissingRef;Ajv.$dataMetaSchema=c;var p="http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema";var v=["removeAdditional","useDefaults","coerceTypes","strictDefaults"];var m=["/properties"];function Ajv(e){if(!(this instanceof Ajv))return new Ajv(e);e=this._opts=u.copy(e)||{};setLogger(this);this._schemas={};this._refs={};this._fragments={};this._formats=l(e.format);this._cache=e.cache||new i;this._loadingSchemas={};this._compilations=[];this.RULES=f();this._getId=chooseGetId(e);e.loopRequired=e.loopRequired||Infinity;if(e.errorDataPath=="property")e._errorDataPathProperty=true;if(e.serialize===undefined)e.serialize=n;this._metaOpts=getMetaSchemaOptions(this);if(e.formats)addInitialFormats(this);if(e.keywords)addInitialKeywords(this);addDefaultMetaSchema(this);if(typeof e.meta=="object")this.addMetaSchema(e.meta);if(e.nullable)this.addKeyword("nullable",{metaSchema:{type:"boolean"}});addInitialSchemas(this)}function validate(e,r){var t;if(typeof e=="string"){t=this.getSchema(e);if(!t)throw new Error('no schema with key or ref "'+e+'"')}else{var a=this._addSchema(e);t=a.validate||this._compile(a)}var s=t(r);if(t.$async!==true)this.errors=t.errors;return s}function compile(e,r){var t=this._addSchema(e,undefined,r);return t.validate||this._compile(t)}function addSchema(e,r,t,a){if(Array.isArray(e)){for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++)this.addSchema(e[i],undefined,t,a);return this}var o=this._getId(e);if(o!==undefined&&typeof o!="string")throw new Error("schema id must be string");r=s.normalizeId(r||o);checkUnique(this,r);this._schemas[r]=this._addSchema(e,t,a,true);return this}function addMetaSchema(e,r,t){this.addSchema(e,r,t,true);return this}function validateSchema(e,r){var t=e.$schema;if(t!==undefined&&typeof t!="string")throw new Error("$schema must be a string");t=t||this._opts.defaultMeta||defaultMeta(this);if(!t){this.logger.warn("meta-schema not available");this.errors=null;return true}var a=this.validate(t,e);if(!a&&r){var s="schema 
is invalid: "+this.errorsText();if(this._opts.validateSchema=="log")this.logger.error(s);else throw new Error(s)}return a}function defaultMeta(e){var r=e._opts.meta;e._opts.defaultMeta=typeof r=="object"?e._getId(r)||r:e.getSchema(p)?p:undefined;return e._opts.defaultMeta}function getSchema(e){var r=_getSchemaObj(this,e);switch(typeof r){case"object":return r.validate||this._compile(r);case"string":return this.getSchema(r);case"undefined":return _getSchemaFragment(this,e)}}function _getSchemaFragment(e,r){var t=s.schema.call(e,{schema:{}},r);if(t){var i=t.schema,n=t.root,l=t.baseId;var f=a.call(e,i,n,undefined,l);e._fragments[r]=new o({ref:r,fragment:true,schema:i,root:n,baseId:l,validate:f});return f}}function _getSchemaObj(e,r){r=s.normalizeId(r);return e._schemas[r]||e._refs[r]||e._fragments[r]}function removeSchema(e){if(e instanceof RegExp){_removeAllSchemas(this,this._schemas,e);_removeAllSchemas(this,this._refs,e);return this}switch(typeof e){case"undefined":_removeAllSchemas(this,this._schemas);_removeAllSchemas(this,this._refs);this._cache.clear();return this;case"string":var 

....The error message code continued





TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at 9041 (E:\Programming\TM\test\.yarn\__virtual__\next-virtual-a4f48e3656\0\cache\next-npm-14.1.0-a62036d298-077fd76a6f.zip\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\conf\index.js:1:105383)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (E:\Programming\TM\test\.yarn\__virtual__\next-virtual-a4f48e3656\0\cache\next-npm-14.1.0-a62036d298-077fd76a6f.zip\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\conf\index.js:15:28574)
    at E:\Programming\TM\test\.yarn\__virtual__\next-virtual-a4f48e3656\0\cache\next-npm-14.1.0-a62036d298-077fd76a6f.zip\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\conf\index.js:15:28861
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Programming\TM\test\.yarn\__virtual__\next-virtual-a4f48e3656\0\cache\next-npm-14.1.0-a62036d298-077fd76a6f.zip\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\conf\index.js:15:28905)
    at loadCJSModule (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:271:3)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:308:7)
    at ModuleJob.runSync (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:209:17)
    at require (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:256:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Programming\TM\test\.yarn\__virtual__\next-virtual-a4f48e3656\0\cache\next-npm-14.1.0-a62036d298-077fd76a6f.zip\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\storage.js:12:54)
    at loadCJSModule (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:271:3)

Node.js v21.6.2
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i edit the previous comment :I am sorry for yarn berry:

> you might need to make some edits on next.config.js file,

did u check this

```
    // next.config.js
module.exports = {
  experimental: { esmExternals: false }
}
```

Comment: First of all I am using yarn berry - the latest yarn version. I have problem with command or program `yarn dev` which starts nextjs development server, but I am having problem with it. It is giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

node 20.5.1 works. it does not work after 20.6.0 version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).